# Css Image Background Size

Tags: css, image, background

I've been working in the css of my website and I got a problem with the background image. At the beginning the image is okay, however when i make a scroll, it gets off. I tried to fix the problem using a 100% size to the image. It works but when i do more scroll it gets off again.
My css is this:

```
background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg")
background-repeat: no-repeat
background-position: auto
webkit-background-size: cover
moz-background-size: cover
o-background-size: cover
background-size: 100% auto
```

Anyone can help me please!

Comment: Can you show us the problem in action?

Comment: It would definitely help for you to show us the problem with a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it gets off"?  Is the background image having a really good time, perhaps?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is a useful way to share an example.

Comment: You need semicolons at the end of the lines...

Answer (score 0):

You can use : Backstretch a jQuery Plugin.

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Demo inside :)

Comment: Not with [tag:CSS], he can't.

Comment: thanks! i already solved the problem. Basically i had to put background-attachment: fixed; and that's it! Florian thanks for the plugin, i didn't know and it seems to be cool :)